# Charset UTF-8 encoding error on VUE CLI 3 project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, utf-8, webstorm, vue-cli

I create a project through `VUE CLI 3` and its working fine on command `yarn serve`. However, I add `UTF-16` on **style.scss** file and then change into `@charset "UTF-8"` again and I got following error

> ��@charset "UTF-8";
>   Blockquote
>
> ^
>   Only UTF-8 documents are currently supported; your document appears to be UTF-16 (big endian)
>         in /Users/codesign004/Momin/square-frontend/src/assets/css/style.scss (line 1, column 1)

but I still keep 'UTF-8' charset , then why should I got the error! moreover, I use `webstorm` for project scaffolding.

Comment: Could this help? "[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)"

Comment: Yes! It was a helpful article, but what I have to do with this problem!

Comment: Not knowing the details of Vue, I would deduce from HTML: Just adding some charset directive into an HTML page does not change the actual binary encoding of that HTML page. Probably you need to convert the actual byte representation of your file from UTF-16 to UTF-8. [See the Webstorm manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-individual-file-encoding.html).

Comment: Finally, the problem solved! I remove the `style.scss`  file  and generate a new one.